# Не могу вывести 2 максимальных числа в массиве

Tags: java

```
public class MaxAndMin {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = System.in;
        Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        String sNum1 = bufferedReader.readLine();
        String sNum2 = bufferedReader.readLine();
        String sNum3 = bufferedReader.readLine();
        String sNum4 = bufferedReader.readLine();
        int a = Integer.parseInt(sNum1);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(sNum2);
        int c = Integer.parseInt(sNum3);
        int d = Integer.parseInt(sNum4);

        int[] age = new int[]{a, b, c, d};
        Arrays.sort(age, Collections.reverseOrder());

        System.out.println(age[0][1]);
    }
}
```

Пишет ошибку Array type expected; found: 'int'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ты выводишь не два элемента, а элемент двумерного массива.
Чтобы вывести два максимальных элемента, допустим, через пробел, в твоем случае следует написать:

```
System.out.println(age[0] + " " + age[1]);
```

В Java можно создавать многомерные массивы: двумерные, трехмерные и так до 255-мерного массива. 
Двумерный массив можно представить как матрицу(или массив массивов, массив, каждый элемент которого тоже массив).
Допустим, если бы ты объявили свой массив так:

```
int[][] age = new int[2][2];

age[0][0] = 1;
age[0][1] = 2;
age[1][0] = 3;
age[1][1] = 4;
```

То создали бы массив из двух элементов, причем каждый из этих элементов сам в то же время является массивом.
Представить это можно примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также, на будущее, часть

```
 InputStream inputStream = System.in;
 Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
```

Можно записать как

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Эту часть

```
String sNum1 = bufferedReader.readLine();
String sNum2 = bufferedReader.readLine();
String sNum3 = bufferedReader.readLine();
String sNum4 = bufferedReader.readLine();
int a = Integer.parseInt(sNum1);
int b = Integer.parseInt(sNum2);
int c = Integer.parseInt(sNum3);
int d = Integer.parseInt(sNum4);

int[] age = new int[]{a, b, c, d};
```

Как

```
int[] age = new int[4];

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    age[i] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень подробно

Comment: Применил все рекомендации, но все равно не работает
в строке Arrays.sort(age, Collections.reverseOrder()); ругается на "age", пишет:
Required type:T[] Provided:int[] reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that int[] conforms to T[]

Comment: Тот метод сортировки, что вы используете(с компаратором) требует в качестве первого аргумента массив объектов. int же является примитивом, из-за этого ошибка.
Можно пойти двумя путями:
1) Изменить 
int[] age = new int[4];
На 
Integer[] age = new Integer[4];
Но мне он кажется не лучшим здесь, как и сам обратный порядок сортировки. Это переусложнение.
Вместо этого можно оставить int[], но использовать обычную сортировку(по возрастанию):
Arrays.sort(age);
И потом достать два максимальных числа так:
int size = age.length;
System.out.println(age[size - 1] + " " + age[size - 2]);

Answer (score 1):

Вам не кажется, что это как-то сложновато...

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class MaxAndMin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
        Stream.of(sc.nextLine(), sc.nextLine(), sc.nextLine(), sc.nextLine())
                .map(s->Integer.valueOf(s))
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .limit(2).forEach(System.out::println);        
    }

}
```